# Peach Down Smash Landing All Hits

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

In SSB: Melee, Peach has an especially strong attack in the form of her [down smash](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Peach_(SSBM)/Down_smash) ("The Meat Grinder"), which as the wiki mentions, can deal 64.96% damage if all the hits land. When all the hits are landed, the opponent is effectively trapped in the down smash, taking huge amounts of damage, and often ending up being spit out in a random direction with great force. With this in mind:

**How can I maximize my chances of landing all of these hits?**

I've noticed that it is much easier to land all the hits against larger, heavier characters like Bowser or Ganondorf (probably because they cannot escape the attacks, and because they are more vulnerable to being hit by all the hit boxes). But how can I maximize my chances of landing all of the hits against smaller characters too? Is there a strategy that helps? Or is it more about timing and practice? Is it even possible to land all the hits against smaller, lighter characters like Pichu or Kirby?

Comment: Not only heavy characters, but fast-fallers too, like Fox and Falco. As for guaranteeing the hits on other characters though, it's kind of a toss up. At a high level, melee is very technical; smash DI allows a player to mash their way out of multi-hitting moves like peach's d-smash and fox's up-air. I don't have a definite answer other than speculation from watching high level peach play.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Yeah that's precisely why I'm asking. I see pros often being able to pull it off, even at high levels of play, but I'm curious how given the existence of smash DI and teching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How can I maximize my chances of landing all of these hits?**

DSmash them while they [DI](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Directional_influence) down and in dsmash (see bullet 1), or position yourself so that the combination of their starting position and the knockback of initial hits sends your opponent into the subsequent hits (bullet 2)

- In order for Peach's downsmash to hit multiple times, the other character needs to be "sucked in" to the hitboxes. The hitboxes of dsmash send you down and in at a [reasonably low (140 degree) angle](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Peach_(SSBM)/Down_smash#Overview), so under no-DI or optimal-DI (up), most standard characters in normal play (so not giga bowser, metal characters) will only be hit by 1-2 hits before the knockback raises them above the hitboxes, [so for maximal damage you want opponent to DI down and in.](https://youtu.be/0591KCrrqs0?t=09s) You can accomplish this by attempting to condition your opponent to attempt to crouch cancel your attacks (which acts as DI down) or attempt to exploit natural situations when your opponent would be holding down (Fox attempts a drill-shine on you but lands short and you dsmash him- he's holding down because of the drill-shine inputs & takes large amounts of damage if he doesn't release down fast enough)
- Having the initial hitboxes of dsmash knock opponents into the follow-up hits is usually accomplished by dsmash on a platform and having your opponent jump into it. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0Z6xWKeMSU) roughly demonstrates what I'm talking about (turnip also adds knockback, but if you slow the video down you can see how the first two hits work)

Comment: With respect to point 1, do you have any advice for how to actually condition my opponent? I understand what I need to do, but do you have advice for how to actually do it? For point 2, is it only going to be limited to platform play? Does this mean that this strategy would not work on stages like Final Destination?

Comment: point 1: Same way you condition someone in any fighting game - by choosing your offensive options as peach such that CC is an optimal response, then mixing it up with down smash when they don't expect it. I play fox so I'm not as familiar with peach's options, but I don't attempt to CC _anything_ in the matchup because of how easily downsmash can cost me a stock.

Comment: point 2: You asked for the best way to maximize chances of landing multiple down smash hits, and people jumping at you from directly below is one of them. You might be able to pull it off in an edge guard situation on FD, but depending on what angle you come up at you may be able to SDI in and walljump/tech the hit.

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein I want to add that I've provided a high level idea on how to accomplish this. Read match-up/Peach-specific guides on smashboards or other SSBM resources for more specific answers. They have threads upon threads of discussion on how to best accomplish what you're asking, and will likely be a better resource. I also edited #1 because I realized that you could also capitalize on their "errors" instead of conditioning for CC

Comment: In casual play, I would not recommend trying to go for the maximized down smash very often. In low level competitive play, a common mistake against Peach would be to crouch cancel too much. While crouch canceling decreases knockback a lot, especially at low damage, it is risky due to how damaging the down smash is. One way for conditioning would be to use a lot of otherwise safe moves that crouch cancel can beat (e.g. floating aerials at SH height?), then mix up with down smash once the opponent forms it into a habit. Pros have their own methods, crafted by deliberate practice over many years.