# What can Peach's neutral special (Toad Guard) actually block?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

Given my previous questions on [Peach](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/309697/peach-down-smash-landing-all-hits) and [countering](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/309825/what-projectiles-can-mario-dr-marios-cape-reflect), this questions seems like a natural extension:

What can be blocked using Peach's [neutral special](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Toad_(move)) (*Toad Guard*)?

The SSBM wiki page above says nothing about what can actually be blocked by Toad, and only says:

> Upon being hit, Toad will emit a damaging shower of spores. Unlike Roy or Ike's Counter which increases in damage when countering stronger attacks, Toad's spores do the same damage (3% each for a total of 18%) and knockback regardless of the power of the blocked attack. The spores themselves can be absorbed, and the move is in fact the only counterattack that fires projectiles when activated.

Melee's instruction manual is also scarce in detail:

> Counter enemy attacks by blocking them with Toad.

So what attacks can actually be blocked? Is it all ranged attacks? Physical attacks? Some combination of the two?

To avoid some confusion I noticed in previous questions, this question is asking specifically about Super Smash Bros: Melee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer: Any attack or projectile.**

Ordinary counters in Smash Bros. (including Peach, Marth, Corrin, etc.) are activated by any ordinary offensive hitboxes, i.e., attacks which deal damage upon connecting. Projectiles and physical attacks both have this property, and Peach can counter both.

Note that counters are activated regardless of whether the incoming attack causes flinching/knockback. Fox's laser, for example, can trigger a counter.

Examples of non-offensives hitboxes which don't activate counters include wind, water, and grabs.

Certain hitboxes have an "unblockable" property. Unblockable hitboxes will hit their target even if they are shielding or countering. In Melee, I suspect most unblockable hitboxes are found in stage hazards, such as the acid in Brinstar. In later Smash games, many items and Final Smashes are also unblockable.

Source: playing a lot of Smash and having experience modding Brawl movesets. I'm not familiar with Melee's "offensive collision" (hitbox) definitions specifically, but I have good reason to believe they're pretty much the same.

Comment: Interesting, so you're claiming that all attacks and projectiles (other than environmental hazards) will be blocked by Toad?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: Could you add that to your answer somewhere? Also, do you have any sources for further reading about this stuff? Maybe some links to some sources on the different types of hitboxes, counters generally, etc, just so there is some more information other than your opinion?

Comment: I would like to add sources, but most of this knowledge is basically only documented in tutorials for the Smash modding community.

Comment: Hmm ok, without those extra sources I think I'll wait a day or two before accepting this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Peach can block most attacks with the exception of counterattacks.  This includes both ranged and melee attacks.

Comment: Final Smashes in Melee?

Comment: Final Smashes were only introduced in Brawl (whereas my question specifically asks about Melee). Otherwise, do you have any sources?

Comment: Oops, I always mix up Brawl and Melee.  Sorry, editing now

Answer (score 0):

As briefly described in this [link](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Toad_(Counterattack))

> Toad can be used as a shield that cancels (but not reflects) projectiles, or a multi-hit attack.

I've tested this against Link's Boomerang attack. Toad blocked the attack but the spore effect was out of range making it pretty useless. Strike attacks were blocked and the spore effect actually made contact.

An interesting but primarily opinion based FAQ about Peach and her moves, can be found [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/gamecube/516492-super-smash-bros-melee/faqs/21335).

Comment: Have you actually tested this yourself? I think the language is more ambiguous than you present it to be

Comment: Tested and edited accordingly.