# What is Special about Yoshi's Egg Shield?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

Continuing my [trend](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/309825/what-projectiles-can-mario-dr-marios-cape-reflect) of asking [Melee](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/309697/peach-down-smash-landing-all-hits) questions in [recent days](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310137/what-can-peachs-neutral-special-toad-guard-actually-block):

In Super Smash Bros: Melee, Yoshi uses his egg as a shield instead of the normal shield that other players use.

[image]

**Functionally, what is special about this egg as compared to the normal shield?**

I've found these references on the [Melee wiki](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Shield#Yoshi.27s_shield) (emphases mine):

> Yoshi has a different shield from that of other characters'. Instead of using a bubble, he uses an egg for protection. **This egg does not shrink, preventing any attempts at shield stabbing.**

And also:

> Also, Yoshi has been known to **randomly perfect shield** (not completely understood, but may have something to do with the egg remaining full size), and is also invincible during his shielding animation.

Are the only unique characteristics of Yoshi's egg shield that the egg prevents shield-stabbing, and can randomly perfect shield? If so, is there more information on this random perfect shielding phenomenon? If not, what else is unique about Yoshi's egg shield?

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question.  If there were any other special properties of the shield, they would likely be noted in the wiki.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann It's possible, though I suspect there are additional properties that may not have been captured in the wiki page I linked that may be known to more experienced players who frequent Arqade

Answer (score 4):

- Yoshi's light shield makes him slide much further than any other character in the game:
  [image: animated GIF of the above]
- Yoshi suffers [no shield stun](https://smashboards.com/threads/yoshis-shield.351632/#post-16557281)

Answer (score 3):

There's one more special property I know of. Unlike other shields, Yoshi cannot jump out of shield. In competative play, this limits his out-of-shield options, making him prone to shield pressure and grabs.